# Cannot run program ng

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot application with Angular 5.

My **npm**, **node** and **angular/cli** are well installed

1. npm -v: 6.4.1
2. node -v: v8.9.1
3. ng -v:  6.2.3

The section of my *pom.xml* file where the **ng command** appears:

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm-install-build</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>ng</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

When I try ti compile my project using mvn -U clean install, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Command execution failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ng" (in directory "C:\Users\AN5810BN\intellj-workspace\stmms-cdc-async\stmms-cdc-async-service\src\main\ui"): CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier sp▒cifi▒ est introuvable
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:61)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:279)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:336)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:804)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:751)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:313)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier sp▒cifi▒ est introuvable
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.P
```

How can I solce this problem ?

Comment: Do you have angular cli installed gobally?

Comment: open command prompt and run ng command.. do you see any error there?

Comment: @Akshay I installed angular cli using **npm install -g @angular/cli** but I did not instertand what do you mean with globally ?

Comment: @Ritesh no there is no error it shows all ng options like add build config ..

Comment: -g means global and can be executed directly from command prompt

Comment: If this problem is in windows then you might have to use **ng.cmd** instead of **ng**

Answer (score 0):

The local ng command works for me, and to run this command we use ***$ npm run ng build***

So I replaced the section of pom.xml in the question with :

```
 <execution>
                        <id>npm-ng-build</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>ng</argument>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

And it works fine